# How to redirect to root_path on InvalidLocale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to redirect to the main page if locale doesn't exist. I did try

```
begin
  rescue i18n::InvalidLocale
  redirect_to "/#{session[:lang]}"
end
```

in the routes, but it doesn't help me. What else can I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rescue_from on the controller level:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from 18n::InvalidLocale, with: :locale_not_found

  private

    def locale_not_found
      redirect_to "/#{session[:lang]||I18n.default_locale}"
    end
end
```